# Are there existing python bindings to the FlyCapture API?

Tags: python, opencv, flycapture

I'm trying to write some code using OpenCV. My sensor is from Point Grey Systems, and it uses the FlyCapture API to grab images. I'd like to grab those images and do some stuff in OpenCV to them, using Python. FlyCapture is all C/C++, so I'm firing up SWIG to create the bindings. Am I reinventing the wheel? Do python bindings for FlyCapture already exist somewhere that I don't know about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of FlyCapture 2.11 there are official Point Grey / FLIR python wrappers.  I've used the python 2.7 so far.

[image]

the pyflycapture2 is still available as well...
just started using this wrapper last week [pyflycapture2](https://github.com/jordens/pyflycapture2)
working well so far with my FireFly MV USB

Answer (score 2):

Here's a new Cython wrapper I started for the FlyCapture V1 API:

https://github.com/kbrafford/pyfly1

It also has some wx.Python demos showing it working and allowing you to assess performance.

Answer (score 1):

If the Python *language* is your only restriction, you may use the wrappers for [FlyCapture from the JavaCPP Presets](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/tree/master/flycapture) by calling the appropriate functions via [Jython](http://www.jython.org/).

Comment: That's very interesting. I never thought to look for Jython bindings. I'm using regular old python, but there's no reason I couldn't switch. That said, I switched from SWIG to Boost.Python, and my binding is almost complete. If that doesn't work out, Jython it is.